# Is it possible to load common controls through an MFC extension dll

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an MFC Extension DLL which is making use of the SysLink Control and I am attempting to call "InitCommonControlsEx" to load the Comctl32 library so that when I open the dialog from my main program through the extension dll the control shows.

But the control only appears when I call the InitCommonControlsEx in my main program.

I am using the pragma to include the correct version of the library as described in the documentation.

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

Is there a way I can load the library through my MFC extension DLL so that whenever it is used, the caller does not have to worry about initialising the common controls.

Comment: I can't find an *authoritative* reference but I think you'll *have* to call it from your main application. The Windows GUI stuff (and MFC) are very fussy about calling modules and their contexts.

Comment: I believe this is supported, by defining a preprocessor symbol that escapes me. Something with `ISOLATION_AWARE`.

Comment: [Supporting Visual Styles in MFC Snap-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/mmc/supporting-visual-styles-in-mfc-snap-ins) explains the underlying concepts. Be prepared to put a lot of little pieces together, with search engines frequently providing not even a full page of results. This is going to be a rough ride.